# Filling a sparse array with nulls (like zipping two arrays)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, underscore.js

I have two arrays. The first one is just a list of some numbers, say, `magicNumbers = [1,2,3,15,33]`. The second one is an array of objects, all having a property `magic`, like that: `magicObjects = [ { 'magic': 1 }, {'magic: 2}, {'magic': 15} ]`

I need to create a new array, containing objects from `magicObject`, in the same order as value of `magic` property is in the `magicNumbers` array, and those places from `magicNumbers` that that do not have a corresponding object in `magicObjects` should be filled with `null`. In our example, this should give:
`[ { 'magic': 1 }, {'magic: 2}, null, {'magic': 15}, null ]`

It's quite easy to implement it in a straightforward manner with `_.map()` and `_.find()`:

> `_.map(magicNumbers, 
>       function(num) {
>           return _.find(magicObjects, 
>               function(v) { return v.magic == num }
>               ) || null;
>       });`

Any ideas how do it properly in a javascript-way, with underscore.js, or maybe just more effective?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually this is done by populating a map `id: object` and fetching objects from the map as you go. So you get `N+M` performance instead of `N*M`:

```js
console.info=function(x){document.write('<pre>'+JSON.stringify(x,0,3)+'</pre>')}
//--

magicNumbers = [1,2,3,15,33];
magicObjects = [ { 'magic': 1 }, {'magic': 2}, {'magic': 15} ];

var mapping = {};
magicObjects.forEach(o => mapping[o.magic] = o);

var result = magicNumbers.map(n => mapping[n] || null);

console.info(result);
```

Comment: Thanks, that's valid in my case since magic values are unique (I just would use `_.indexBy` to transform the array to map)